# I want to find city, state information based upon the postal code and country code

Tags: google-api

I want to find out county, city, state, phoneAreaCode, latitude, longitude, cityStateKey based upon two inputs i.e. postal code and country

I tried going through the google api documentation, but their documentation is quite overwhelming.

input - 
"CountryCode": "US",
"postalCode": "60090"

Output -
"provinceCode": "IL",
"county": "COOK",
"phoneAreaCode": "847/312/224/630/708",
"latitude": 42.124293,
"longitude": -87.924184,
"cityStateKey": "W15521",
"cityName": "WHEELING"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the research found that "Find Place Request" from Google's Places API is the best fit for this requirement.

Here is the request and response:

Request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=06850&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,geometry,types&key=API_KEY
```

Response:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "New York, NY 10029, USA",
            "geometry": {
                "location": {
                    "lat": 40.79164069999999,
                    "lng": -73.94479939999999
                },
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 40.79299052989272,
                        "lng": -73.94344957010728
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 40.79029087010727,
                        "lng": -73.94614922989271
                    }
                }
            },
            "name": "New York, NY 10029",
            "types": [
                "postal_code"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```